# Google fonts are not appearing (using cpanel)

Tags: css, fonts, google-font-api

for some reason my google fonts aren't appearing in my preview!

my css looks like this

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:700,400);

html, body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  color:#2E3192;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif !important;
  background-image: url("images/backgroundimg.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  font-size: 13pt;
  overflow-x: hidden;
 }
```

i'm pretty sure thats all correct as it was working in codepen. is it just because im previewing or something?

thanks

Comment: working http://jsfiddle.net/k73k6vqy/

Comment: Sometimes Apache doesn't play nice with fonts. You might need to define font mimetypes in your .htaccess.

Comment: Are you sure the @import is the first thing in your CSS?

Comment: definitely first thing in CSS, however, i now seems to be working today! im using my laptop instead of a apple mac desktop. Weird! thanks though :)

Answer (score 2):

If your "preview" is https, that would explain it. The browser might block insecure requests. Try to reference the Google import without `http:`.

```
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:700,400);
```

An URL starting with `//` is protocol relative. Whatever protocol the parent document uses will be used.

Comment: its still not working but it seems to be just this computer! thanks